# iOS 9: Gesture Recognizer was setup in a storyboard/xib to be added to more than one view (not working)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

Using iOS 9 and facing a problem with a `UITapGestureRecognizer`. I have a ViewController-A with a `UITableView`. I have added a tableViewCell which has a textLabel. I want to implement tap on the textLabel. So if I tap on textLabel -- it should print on Console or do anything else

**Issue:** TapRecogniser is not working. Getting the below error:

[image]

Following is what I have done:

1) Added a `UITapGestureRecognizer' on the textLabel (From StoryBoard). Enabled User Interaction for the textLabel (the error even now)

2) Following is the IBAction:

```
@IBAction func nameTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
   print("a")
}
```

3) CellForRowAtIndexPath

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! ThirdViewCell!
    cell.nameLabel?.text = "XYZ"

    let nameTapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("nameTap:"))
    nameTapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    cell.nameLabel?.addGestureRecognizer(nameTapRecognizer)
    return cell
}
```

**P.S:** 
1) This was working in iOS 8. I have checked..There are no duplicates (there is only one tap recognizer in the entire file and its linked to the textLabel)

2) I don't want to use didSelectRowAtIndexPath method as I need to implement TapGestureRecognizer for more textLabels within the tableViewCell.

Comment: the tap is not working..nothing happens after implementing the code..i have taken a screenshot of the error and posted in the question

Comment: Get rid of the UITapGestureRecognizer that you added in the Storyboard.  It should only be set up in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

are you see the error console `Label`, and the property as `UserInteractionEnabled  = NO;` see the screen shot

[image]

try this

```
let nameTapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("nameTap:"))
nameTapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
cell.nameLabel?.tag = indexPath.row // add this 
nameTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1 // add this 
nameTapRecognizer.delegate =self
cell.nameLabel?.userInteractionEnabled = true  // add this 
cell.nameLabel?.addGestureRecognizer(nameTapRecognizer)

// method
func nameTap(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: gesture.view!.tag, inSection: 0)
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UITableViewCell

// Do whatever you want.
}
```

Comment: use anyone Gesture like use Storyboard based else use programmatically ,  I think r u tried in both

Comment: a followup question:  in the nameTap I want to perform a segue to ViewController - B..I have put the following command: performSegueWithIdentifier("segueToVCB", sender: self)...its working fine..only thing is that I want to send the row number to VC-B..I know how prepareForSegue works...but not sure how to send row number..I saw you have used the 'tag' but unsure how to use it in "prepareForSegue"..will be great if you can let me know